# Merge method doesn't make LAZY fetch mapping available

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb

Here is a simple `One-to-Many` relationship: `Order` to `Items`. One order can have many items within. And there is an association table `ORDERITEMSMAPPING` between the two entities, following relation is established in Order.java:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "ORDERITEMSMAPPING",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID"))
@OrderBy("typeId, shortName")
@JsonIgnore
private List<Item> Items;
```

The reason to make above mapping as `FetchType.LAZY` is data load is huge for `Eager` mapping

However, from Java EE side, we need to call getter to find all items from specific one order using Order's `getItems()` method, but in one transaction.

Here is the work out in Order entity:

```
public List<Item> getItems(Order order){
    if(this.items==null){
        List<Item> items= new ArrayList<Item>();
        EntityManager em = Order.entityManager();
        Order merged = em.merge(order);
        items = merged.getItems();
        em.close();
        return items;
    }else{
        return this.items;
    }
}
```

However, above method doesn't work, still return `null` items even call

merged.getOrders();

I tought `merge()` method can return a managed copy of the entity and make `LAZY` mapping available, but it seems not true.

BTW i am using OpenJPA but seems JPA vendor is not an issue I guess. It's probably i am still not very profound on entity management cycles. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: If the collection is null on the order being merged, merging it will not fix the problem.  It should not be null, and instead just inaccessible when detached - some providers throw an exception when the context is lost, while others might allow it.  But null means the collection has no value.  Try using em.refresh(order) and then accessing the collection if you are sure there is data in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You're masking the member variable from scope at this line:

```
List<Item> items= new ArrayList<Item>();
```

By declaring `List<Item> items`, you make the `items` variable point to an object on the stack for the entirety of that `if {` block, instead of `this.items` like you intend.

Try `this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();`, and `return this.items` instead.

It's also a good idea to use a naming convention for member variables in your code to avoid situations like this occurring.  Naming the variable `m_items` can go a long way.

Comment: also denominations is ignored.  I assume it is the complete list that was meant to be returned or used in populating the item list